# Does primary index in mysql table automatically have a value when new row is added?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

So, assuming I have a table, with 20 columns, and I want to insert data to them, and the first column is just a primary index, which will automatically have a numerical value if I don't assign one to it. Primary index has auto increment on.

So my question is, do I always have to do it like this (which is pretty annoying and slow)

```
INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6) VALUES (col1value,col2value,col3value,col4,value,col5value,col6value)
```

or, could I just specify the values (assuming that I'm filling every column except the primary index) like this

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (col1values,col2values,col3values,col4values,col5values,col6values)
```

or will it break the table?

Comment: How is the first slow? Because you have to type the column names?

Comment: @ypercube yes. I'd rather not type it if I don't have to.

Comment: Actually, it'll work: INSERT INTO table VALUES (null,col2values,col3values,col4values,col5values,col6values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't use your second solution, unless you provide as many values as field count. You can still provide primary key value with `NULL`. MySQL will then replace it by an auto-incremented value (assuming your column is PRIMARY KEY + AUTO_INCREMENT).

Nevertheless, the first solution is perfectly fine.

Comment: The first solution is absolutely horrible to use, as I have to first type the column names. But using `NULL` will do the job?

Answer (score 0):

tldr; You need to define the columns you are inserting into.

Mysql assumes that when you don't put in the column names like below

```
INSERT INTO table (column_name1, column_name2, column_name3)
```

that you are going to define all the columns in your value definition later. Without defining the column names, it wouldn't know which row to skip for the primary key.

An example of this would be if you had the primary key as column_name2 in the above example.

Comment: Yes I know that. I think that you didn't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is correct.
In the second one you can specify the primary key attribute as null or using `INSERT INTO table VALUES('',col2values,col3values,col4values,col5values,col6values)` assuming that the first field is primary key.

Comment: A `NULL` and an empty string are not the same thing.